# Ассоциативный массив в php

Tags: php

При попытке реализовать передачу данных с контроллера в шаблон, столкнулся с непонятным (для меня) поведением цикла ассоциативного массива

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

У меня в массиве ключи тоже данные, это могут быть либо объекты или строки, но почему-то `$key` является числом, это меня удивило, возможно кто-то может рассказать как вообще работает цикл foreach, принцип работы

Не много объяснение, как работает цикл я знаю, меня интересует как он работает внутри, принцип работы. 
Ключи в ас. массиве остаются, такими как и должны быть, а говорю за переменную $key, которая объявляется в инициализации цикла foreach, мне кажется по логике она должна принимать значения диапазона моих ключей, а вместо этого она принимает - (1,2,3,..)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор вопроса проигнорировал правило русскоязычности данного ресурса.

Comment: Проверьте, точно-ли у вас ассофиативный массив. Какой результат выдает `print_r()` с вашим массивом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Объект ключом массива быть не может.
2. Если ключи массива стали цифрами - скорее всего, к массиву была применена какая-либо функция, не сохраняющая ключи.
3. Для того, чтобы найти причину ошибки самостоятельно, нужно обладать базовыми навыками отладки. То есть, не объявить массив где-то в начале, а потом удивляться выводу, а **последовательно** пройти по цепочке преобразований этого массива, на каждом шаге выводя его содержимое с помощью `var_dump()` - и проблемная функция сразу будет найдена. После этого либо заменить функцию на сохраняющую ключи, либо задать конкретный вопрос на СО по конкретному куску кода.

Comment: Приведите пример массива. Выполните `var_dump(массив);` прямо перед `foreach`. То что вы описываете - несколько странная ситуация. В моей практике подобное не случалось. И, всё-таки, пишите по-русски, уважайте правила подсайта. Не поймите как придирку. На англоязычном сайте этот вопрос удалили бы без пререканий.

Comment: Все, я разобрался! Это была моя ошибка. Я добавлял новые элементы неправильно:`$array = ['email@email.em' => [1, 2,3, 4]];
    $array[] = ['email2@email.em' => [1, 2,3, 4]];
    $array[] = ['email2@email.em' => [1, 2,3, 4]];`  В результате мой ас. массив превратился в индексной и дал такой результат `email@email.em 
0 
1`. Спасибо за подсказки.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что в PHP есть только одно представление множества - это массив, и он **всегда** выглядит как набор пар ключ-значение. Даже если ключ не написан явно, в PHP все равно предусмотрено поле под него, и PHP сотворит этот ключ сам, это будет числом навроде тех, которые вы видите. Таким образом массив в PHP пытается сэмулировать одновременно HashTable и Vector, во всяком случае, это мое предположение. Видимо, вы как-то неверно понимаете значение ключа, потому что:

> это могут быть либо объекты или строки

Ключом в PHP может быть только строка, либо целое число, причем строка, состоящая из одного целого числа (например, `'123'`) будет приведена к этому числу. Единственный способ сделать так, чтобы PHP "съел" объект в качестве ключа, который я знаю - это реализовать в нем метод `__toString()`, и тогда в этот момент объект все равно будет заменен строкой.

Foreach же работает довольно просто: пока цикл не дошел по массиву до конца, он подставляет в `$key` следующий ключ, а в `$value` - следующее значение. Вы можете убедиться, что с ключами все так, как я описал, с помощью передачи массива в  `print_r()` или `var_dump()`.

Как написал @Ипатьев, ключи могут "потеряться" в результате преобразования массива с помощью функций `array_*()`. С помощью отладчика или того же `var_dump()` вы сможете найти этот момент.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте [тут](http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles)

Доступно написано с примерами.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, есть правила. Довольно глупо после этого говорить нам "подучить" в такой ситуации. А, во-вторых, имеет смысл с уважением отнестись прежде всего к другим и не лезть со своим уставом.

Comment: Давайте хотя бы тут без политики и штампов

Comment: @tutankhamun, вот именно поэтому и созданы правила, дабы исключать прецеденты.

Comment: Прецеденты чего? У нас что, была опасность уничтожения мира? По-моему вы на ровном месте устраиваете драму.

Comment: @Etki, эм... прецедент к возникновению срача. Это, если угодно, чтобы я уточнил в связи с отсутствием понимания. Драмы нет. Раздражает сознательное наплевание.

Comment: мда... и кто тут срач разводит?

Comment: @TahirBerdyev, тот, кто начал с указаний, кому и чего "подучить".